# Split a data.frame by group into a list of vectors rather than a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dplyr, split

I have a `data.frame` which maps an `id` column to a `group` column, and the `id` column is not unique because the same `id` can map to multiple `group`s:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = paste0("id", sample(1:10,300,replace = T)), group = c(rep("A",100), rep("B",100), rep("C",100)), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'd like to convert this `data.frame` into a `list` where each element is the `id`s in each `group`.

This seems a bit slow for the size of data I'm working with:

```
library(dplyr)
df.list <- lapply(unique(df$group), function(g) dplyr::filter(df, group == g)$id)
```

So I was thinking about this:

```
df.list <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::group_split()
```

Assuming it is faster than my first option, any idea how to get it to return the same output as in the first option rather than a list of `data.frame`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `base R` only with `split`.  It should be faster than the `==` with `unique`

```
with(df, split(id, group))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` we can `pull` the column after the `group_split`.  The `group_split` returns a data.frame/tibble and could be slower compared to the `split` only method above.  But, here, we can make some performance improvements by removing the group column (`keep = FALSE`) and then in the `list`, `pull` the 'id' column to create the `list` of `vector`s

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
     group_split(group, keep = FALSE) %>% 
     map(~ .x %>%
             pull(id))
```

---

Or use `{}` with  pipe

```
df %>%
    {split(.$id, .$group)}
```

Or wrap with `with`

```
df %>%
     with(., split(id, group))
```